# Moving data between databases using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I have 2 identical databases created by same alembic script. One is full of data used on production, second one is empty. I need to move some of the data from one to another. Is there any elegant way how to do this? (please assume there is auto generated `id` which cannot and does not need to be same in databases.)

I was thinking of 2 possible solutions -> select all I want from one db `expunge_all()` and add them to another, or some trickery with `__dict__`. Which would be more elegant?

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off using the dump tools of your DB.

Comment: Well it's like 30 records from few millions that I want to copy. Already managed via `expunge_all()`

Comment: That's good info to add to the question, since it impacts the solution choices. Anyway, for a dump you could perhaps consider using the Core, so there'd be no need to move objects between sessions etc., since you don't (?) need all the ORM features for such a task.

Comment: Yes, thanks this seems useful since I will be doing similar thing between 2 production databases soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
copy = db1.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.someattr == some_attr).all()
db1.expunge_all()
for c in copy:
    db2.add(c)
db2.commit()
```

This seems to work well.